# VSTO - Retrieve editbox value

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Here is my ribbon.xml file :

```
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab label="My Tab" idMso="TabAddIns" >
        <group label="My Group">
          <labelControl label="Input : "/>
          <editBox id="editbox1" label="here"/>
          <button id="go" label="go" onAction="go_click"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
```

Now in the backend part in the `go_click` function I would like to retrieve the value inserted in `editbox1`.

How can I do that? I sneaked around but doesn't found that much.

```
    public void go_click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
          // Try to retrieve content of `editbox1` here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the `onChange` callback for the `editbox` control - it will be called every time the text is modified. The callback takes `IRibbonControl` and a string as parameters.

Comment: So I need to assume that this string cannot be captured by another VSTO plugin that uses the same idQ namespace? If I want to that, what is the best option?

Comment: Correct. Instead of exposing the raw data, you can expose an API accessible through the `Addin.Object` property

Comment: I do not know nor have read about this API thing using Addin.Object. Big mystery. Will try to find some materials about it. I also thought about using Registry and storing everything in it. May be an option (maybe `Addin.Object`is better, will  see. Many thanks.

Comment: Found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions that works like a charm. Thanks Dmitry!